# AngularJS $http.get retrieves an array in unusable format for the ng-data-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I cant to find a way to bind the elements of the array using the data-ng-repeat directive to the html page that contains the script below. The problem is that the Quizes looks like this:

```
[{"quizname":"Quiz 1", "username":"musa"...}]



<script> 
   var app = angular.module("QuizApp");
   app.controller("QuizCntrl",function($scope,$http){
   var onSuccess = function(data, status, headers, config){
   $scope.Quizes = data.getQuizesResult; //Returns an size5, checked it using console.log
  };
 var promise = $http.get("http://localhost:59503/Service1.svc/GetQuizes");
 promise.success(onSuccess);
 });
</script>
```

So when i try doing this:

```
 <div data-ng-controller="QuizCntrl">
     <table>
      ...
       <tr data-ng-repeat = "quiz in Quizes">
          <td>{{quiz.username}}</td>
          <td>{{quiz.quizname}}</td>
        <tr>
       ...
      </table>
```

Nothing gets displayed. In the tutorials and online examples that I've done all arrays look something like this:

```
 $scope.array = [{username: "value".....}]
```

How can i work around those quotations on my field names to use the data-ng-repeat directive? Any small help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What does it output only with "quiz" in angular? The quotes doesn't matter. In both ways they are interpreted as strings, so The Problem must lie elsewhere

Comment: it displayed nothing. Anyway it now works..I'm silly I had misspelled the word repeat with reapeat.

Comment: In your example it was correct. But good it's now working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the example, the quotes doesn't matter.
Maybe you will find your mistake with the example.

And you should be doing this one:

`$http.get("http://localhost:59503/Service1.svc/GetQuizes").then(onSuccess);`

```js
var app = angular.module("QuizApp", []);

app.controller("QuizCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.Quizes = [{"quizname":"Quiz 1", "username":"musa"}, {quizname:"Quiz 2", username:"musa 2"}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="QuizApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="QuizCntrl">
     <table>
       <tr data-ng-repeat = "quiz in Quizes">
          <td>{{quiz.username}}</td>
          <td>{{quiz.quizname}}</td>
        <tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```